vuejs add a modul to js file that is not needed
I am trying to migrate one of my projects form ASP.NET MVC to VueJS (latest). On one of my pages in ASP.NET MVC I have win wheel (this). When I try to add it to the vue page I am getting the following error in colnsole:
ActivateChoice.vue:55 SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/deps/primevue_image.js?v=07215650' does not provide an export named 'Image' (at wheel.js:2:1)
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/deps/primevue_image.js?v=07215650' does not provide an export named 'Image' (at wheel.js:2:1)

In the Sources in the browser I can see, that somehow this line got added:
import {Image, image} from "/node_modules/.vite/deps/primevue_image.js?v=07215650";

and I do not know why.
I imported the winwheel.js file like this:
import * as Winwheel from './../../infrastructure/wheel.js';


//vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import AutoImport from 'unplugin-auto-import/vite';
import Components from 'unplugin-vue-components/vite';
import {PrimeVueResolver} from '@primevue/auto-import-resolver';
import basicSsl from '@vitejs/plugin-basic-ssl';
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url';    

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  esbuild: {
    supported: {
      'top-level-await': true,
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    basicSsl(),
    vue(),
    AutoImport({
      imports: ['vue', 'vue-router'],
      resolvers: [PrimeVueResolver()],
      dirs: ['./src/infrastructure'],
    }),
    Components({
      resolvers: [PrimeVueResolver()],
    }),
  ],
  server: {
    open: '/',
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
        '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
}
});

I also found that someone had already made a wrapper around vuejs (here). I copied the ES6 formated winwheel.js file to my solution, but still the same.
I am usging primevue, and I have configured AutoImport for the primevue;
thnx

" When I try to add it to the vue page" - how exactly do you use primevue? "I have configured AutoImport for the primevue" - how? The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

@EstusFlask I added the vite.config.js if it helps. If need more details, I can provide them

Did you try to use the config primevue suggests? https://primevue.org/autoimport/#unplugin You may no need PrimeVueResolver in AutoImport. I personally advice against using autoimport and other non-spec things, it's pure wild magic that isn't thoroughly documented and can result in unpredictable time losses. In this case it results in import {Image, image} from 'primevue/image', while the correct human-written import would be import Image from 'primevue/image'
